# $U_n=\left(r_n-\frac1{3^n},r_n+\frac1{3^n}\right)$ then $[0,1]\not \subseteq \bigcup_n^\infty U_n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $r_1,r_2,....$ be the list of all rational numbers in $[0,1]$. Let $U_n=\left(r_n-\dfrac1{3^n},r_n+\dfrac1{3^n}\right)$ then $[0,1]\not \subseteq \displaystyle\bigcup_n^\infty U_n$

I cannot prove this because first I dont know we are doing this orderly, I mean If I knew that we start from $0$ and go with this given $U_n$ then I can say that there will be some gap to the $1$ but $r_n$ can be randomly located so their  $\left(r_n-\dfrac1{3^n},r_n+\dfrac1{3^n}\right)$ radius can be big to cover whole $[0,1]$ How can I start

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$[0,1]$ is compact so $[0,1]] \subset \cup_{n=1}^{N} U_n$ fro some $N$. Now you can arrange the finite number of intervals $U_1,U_2,\cdots,U_N$ with increasing order of left end points and get a contradiction (since the total length of $U_i$'s is less than $1$).

Comment: Thank you, by the way can we approach this question in another manner? Can you give me a hint about other methods?